# Tool to extract the header from .dex file

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dex

Is there a tool to extract the header of Android .dex files? I am looking for a pedump like tool .dex file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options

1. baksmali. This produces an annotated binary dump of the dex file (including the header).

   ```
   baksmali -N -D out.dump app.apk
   ```
2. dexdump. This provides a slightly higher level logical dump of the dex file (including most of the fields in the header)

   ```
   dexdump -f app.apk
   ```